# how to split many text in one cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm struggling with problem in google spread sheet
How to split text in one cell if cell looks like below?

Prorudct
Ax2, B, C, D, Ex3

| product |
| --- |
| Ax2, B, C, D, Ex3 |

I'd like to make it like this

| product | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string in A1, try

```
={"Product", "Quantity"; ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(A1, ", ", 0)&if(regexmatch(split(A1, ", ", 0), "x\d*$"), , "x1")), "x"))}
```

Change range to suit.

[image]

If you'd want to process multiple rows and create a sum of the quantity per product, you can try

```
=query(ArrayFormula(split(flatten(split(A1:A4, ", ", 0)&if(regexmatch(split(A1:A4, ", ", 0), "x\d*$"), , "x1")), "x")), "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 label Col1 'Product', sum(Col2) 'Quantity'", 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to aggregate many rows of these strings and that the first string is in A2:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&",",",","x1,"),","))),"x"),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'product', SUM(Col2) 'quantity'"))`

This is a little different from the solution suggested by JPV in that it pre-`FILTER`s results so that you don't have to name the range specifically to avoid errors. It also takes a different approach to the transformation.

**How It Works:**

`FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")`

This assures that the larger formula is only working on non-blank cells in the column to avoid errors.

`&","`

This is appended to the end of every string, so that every element of every string ends with a comma temporarily. This will be used in the following transformation step.

`REGEXREPLACE(_________,",","x1,")`

Every comma is then replaced with `x1,`. Note that even list entries that already have an x2, x3, etc. after them will get this piece added for now. For instance, an original string such as "Ax2, B, C, D, Ex3" will look like this in memory at this point: "Ax2x1, Bx1, Cx1, Dx1, Ex3x1". It won't matter later.

`SPLIT(__________,",")`

Strings will then be `SPLIT` at the comma. For instance, the example string will look like this in memory:

Ax2x1 | Bx1 | Cx1 | Dx1 | Ex3x1

`FLATTEN` will turn these horizontal arrays into one long vertical array.

`TRIM` will cut out superfluous spaces.

So the above entry will now look like this in memory:

Ax2x1

Bx1

Cx1

Dx1

Ex3x1

`SPLIT(_________,"x")`

Now, each of those strings will be `SPLIT` again at the 'x', leaving this:

A | 2 | 1

B | 1

C | 1

D | 1

E | 3 | 1

`QUERY(___________,"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'product', SUM(Col2) 'quantity'"))`

Finally, `QUERY` will act on all of these, `Select`ing only the first column and the sum of the second column per unique element of the first. (The third virtual column will be ignored.) Chosen labels are then assigned to each of the remaining two columns.